# how to write generic typing of multiple provider in one component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

using higher order context provider
but unable to set proper typing of that component.

How to do proper typing

dummy code

```
const ContextA:T = (propA) => { }
const ContextB:U = (propB) => { }
```

Here T & U are s set by 3rd party library such as redux

Now create a component which combine these Context and give a lile below

```
const combineContext =  [ ContextA, ContextB ]

// and set typing like this

type combineContextType = T | U ;
```

this gives error of prop does not match< because both have separate typing and in built

So how can we set typing properly, using generics.

so in future if we add another context then it took automatically of that type